# Function to match a singular word

Tags: javascript, html

**This is for help with a website I am building for class**
[assignment so far](http://analog-gamers.com/assignments/assignment3.html)

Trying to make a function to compare input text to match certain words that I choose. So for this example if the user inputs anything other than `bark` or `Bark` in the text area it should just tell you in console it is incorrect. I plan on using this for a bigger function that passes a true/false that validates the name, date,phone, etc... but now I'm just trying to get this simple code to run in jsfiddle without a "this is not a function" in the console.

HTML

```html
<form name="inputForm" onsubmit="verify() " enctype="text/plain">
  <input id="verify" type="text" name=verify placeholder="Dog talk and tree clothes?" required="required"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var val = document.getElementById('verify').value;
function verify(val){
if(val === 'bark' || val === 'Bark'){
  console.log("yes");
} else {
  console.log("no");
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function validateForm(e) {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById('verify').value;

  const wordsToVerify = ['Bark', 'word2', 'word3', 'etc'];

  // Loop through words array to convert values to Lower case.
  // Please note that you may not need to convert both words and value
  // Use .includes() method to check if input value is included in words array

  const wordFound = wordsToVerify.map(word => word.toLowerCase()).includes(inputValue.toLowerCase());

  if (wordFound) {
    console.log('yes');
    // Do something...
  } else {
    console.log('no');
  }
  // Prevent form submitting until you decide what to do the values
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validateForm()">

  <input id="verify" type="text" name=verify placeholder="Dog talk and tree clothes?" required="required" />

  <button type="submit">submit!</button>

</form>
```

---

Check this [post](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/javascript-tutorial/javascript-form-validation.php) for more scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Cehck out the following snippet . In this we have called the function `verify()` on button click instead of `input="submit"`

```js
function verify(){

  var val = document.getElementById('verify').value;



  if(val.toLowerCase() === 'bark' ){

   console.log("yes");

  } else {

   console.log("no");

  }
 }
```

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>GnG</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="inputForm"  enctype="text/plain">

  <input id="verify" type="text" name="verify" placeholder="Dog talk and tree clothes?" required="required"/>
 </form>
 <button onClick="verify()">
  Submit
 </button>

</body>
</html>
```

If you have any doubt , feel free to ask .